# How to extract a value that does not contain the string "None" in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have 3 columns in my table and need to extract the one that does not contain the word "None".

Example:

[image: Column1 needs new value]

Please help me with VBA code in which I can just extract the value into column1.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking and you really [should make an attempt on your own](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) before posting here

Comment: Is there a problem with my answer ? You accepted it and then rejected it with no explanation.

Comment: It says incorrect formula... I am trying to adjust it now. I believe there is no ";" in If statements its commas.

Comment: @AhmedMajid That depends on your national settings, so yeah if you replace ";" with "," you'll be fine

Comment: awesome thanks! i didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question is tagged as excel-formula as well I offer you a formula based solution:

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(A1="none","",A1),IF(B1="none","",B1),IF(C1="none","",C1))
```

It connects texts of all of the needed cells but ignores cells with "none" in them, pretty straight-forward.